# With ES lint error want to reolve without disabling it or changing rule

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, eslint, lint

While working with the react I have this below error but I dont want to use es-lint-disable

1. With the below code I am getting the lint error of `Do not nest ternary expressions.eslintno-nested-ternary` How to resolve this?

   `getDaySuffix = day => (day === (1 || 21 || 31) ? 'st' : day === (2 || 22) ? 'nd' : day === (3 || 23) ? 'rd' : 'th');`
2. getting this error when I try to do following `Assignment to property of function parameter 'data'.eslintno-param-reassign`

   if (recurrence.month) {
   delete data.date;
   }
3. With below code I am getting an error `Assignment to property of function parameter 'carry'.eslintno-param-reassign`

   ````
         (carry, current) => {
           if (current.field === 'access_group_uuid') {
             carry[current.field] = (carry[current.field] || []).concat(
               current.value,
             );
           } else {
             carry[current.field] = carry[current.field]
               ? [carry[current.field], current.value]
               : current.value;
           }
           return carry;
         },
         {},
       );```
   ````
4. With below code I am getting error of `Unexpected dangling '_' in '_id'.eslintno-underscore-dangle`. here the data I am getting if from backend I cannot change it. How can I resolve lint error?

   ````
      const data = { _id: reporData._id, name: reporData.name };
      const data = {
          _id: reporData._id,
          name: reporData.name,
          emails,
          recurrence: obj.recurrence,
          scheduled_report: true,
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          scheduled_report_id: obj._id,
        };```
   ````

Can anyone help me with this? I trtied searching the error but I found `// eslint-disable-next-line` solution but I don't want that solution. Can please anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Nesting ternary expressions can make code more difficult to understand.
   https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-nested-ternary Define regual function instead.

```
const getDaySuffix = day => {
    if (day === 1 || day === 21 || day === 31) return 'st'
    if (day === 2 || day === 22) return 'nd'
    if (day === 3 || day === 23) return 'rd'
    return 'th'
  }
```

2. This rule aims to prevent unintended behavior caused by modification or reassignment of function parameters. https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-param-reassign Clone data object and work with it.
3. Same as #2. By updating `carry` you mutate this object in original structure. Create new object, update it and return.

```
(carry, current) => {
    const carryClone = {...carry}
    if (current.field === 'access_group_uuid') {
      carryClone[current.field] = (carryClone[current.field] || []).concat(current.value)
    } else {
      carryClone[current.field] = carryClone[current.field] ? [carryClone[current.field], current.value] : current.value
    }
    return carryClone
  }
```

4. This rule disallows dangling underscores in identifiers. https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-underscore-dangle

Object key cannot be `_id`. Use `id` only instead.

```
const data = { id: reporData._id, name: reporData.name };
```

Comment: For dangle issue I have at other places too   like ```if (formData._id)``` and 
     ```if (formData.filters[0]._id)``` How can I fix those?

Comment: You should change all `_id` to `id`. The best place where to do this changes is after/before getting/sending data from/to API. (If you really need name with underscore prefix)

Comment: _ prefix in JS means the property is private, than u can disable this rule. JavaScript Naming Conventions: 
https://www.robinwieruch.de/javascript-naming-conventions

Comment: Accept answer if no more questions. ;)